# Find polygon that traverses all given points with minimal circumference but has a single surface

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

I know about Convex Hull, but convex hull is convex, which isn't what I want. I want a polygon that will always try to minimize it's perimeter however will not have multiple surfaces:

[image]

For example, I don't wanna this to happen:

[image]

I don't even know how to solve this by hand. Hell, when drawing the images above, when I made them more complicated I didn't even know how to connect the points for the lowest perimeter.

I tried to google concave hull, but that's not what I want. I want the polygon to traverse all points.

What should I look for to solve this problem?

Comment: Look for *Travelling Salesman Problem*

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is there anything that forbids travelling salesman from crossing his previous path, eg. as on the second image in question?

Comment: You look for shortest so if crossing makes it shorter (does not make sense) it is taken as best solution. This problem is one of the questions that is mentioned as requiring much computation and awaits an effective algorithm - so if you find one it will be a great discovery.

Comment: The traveling salesman path cannot cross itself, see Fig 4 of this article: http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-tsp